# Class Design and Inheritance

Tags: c#, c++, class, inheritance

I'm new to OO design/programming and have a question I believe is about class design. I will be as precise as I am able in my terminology.

[Edit]
Maybe it boils down to this: I have a list of objects of type base class. Derivative classes are created as specific types of the base class implementing the methods of the base class and some with additional parameters and/or methods specific to the derived type. When I transverse the list, I am working with a base class reference. What is a good way to then access the methods and parameters for a particular variant class? Switch statements and casting? Isn't this bad form in C# and suggest a defect in the class design?

[Original]
Following the example of Stroustrup in the book "The C++ Programming Language", assume I'm writing a graphics program that uses a base class "shape", and classes "circle", "triangle", and "square" which are derived from "shape". According to Stroustrup, the base class must contain member functions required to implement the "full set of operations" for the shape class. In most cases these member functions will be virtual so that the derived classes can implement functionality specific to their shape such as: load, save, draw, rotate, update, etc. This all makes sense to me.

Where I run into difficulty is the impact of the subtle differences between the shape types and the implications of these differences on the base class. For example, consider member functions specific to a particular derived shape. Assume the "circle" shape has a value describing how many line segments to use to approximate the circle (e.g. lineCount). How do I handle setting and updating this value in a way that doesn't start contaminating my base class with virtual member functions the "bubble up" from the specific needs of each of the derived classes?

I ask this because expect to keep a list of type "shape" to track all my objects. I do not expect to have lists of type "circle", "triangle", and "square" where direct access to the circle specific lineCount value could be made and wouldn't keeping these separate lists violate the whole idea of inheritance anyway by either implicitly or explicitly introducing the equivalent of a switch statement with cases for each shape type?

To solve this problem, am I on the right track to think that in addition to obvious member functions like "draw", I must think deeply about the "full set of operations" requirement. So if I have a shape specific value (e.g. lineCount for the circle shape), it must be possible via the member functions of shape, to get/set this value in a general way that is compatible with other (possibly different) values from other shape types. I can only think that the shape class must therefore include a general parameter setting function that may include requiring each derived class to present it's own UI form requesting its particular shape specific parameters. A requirement of the shape class to include UI member functions feels like the shape class is getting too heavy.

Am I thinking about this the right way? Is there a better way to handle the subtle differences in derived classes?

Comment: One way to solve this is to have a `std::map` (or `Dictionary` for C#) of configuration data and a virtual `configure` function you can call to pass in the needed data for each shape type.

Comment: All subclasses should implement the "full set of operations" in the base class. But that doesn't mean that baseclass should support all operations that any subclass might have. Just put such functions only into the subclass that needs it.

Comment: Zac, is your comment related to solving the particular problem of ALL circles needing a lineCount value where one lineCount value stored as a configuration parameter could apply to all circles. If so I believe I understand what you're saying. But my problem is more general, each specific shape type has unique values that are unique to it alone. Is there a solution better than either a "Full set of operations" or using casts/switch statements on the objects of type shape stored in the list?

Comment: @BobC a better solution is to improve design so there would be few or no cases when you need type-specific operation. E.g. `lineCount` seems to be a property of specific rendering algorithm, most probably it shouldn't belong to circle.

Comment: @Konstantin, I am looking at ways to avoid these (apparently) needed differences between the shape types. My example may not be the best using lineCount for a circle, which I agree is about the rendering itself. Perhaps a better example is an "arc". An arc needs a starting and ending angle. These values are specific to an arc and do not apply to a circle, triangle or square. Yet I'd still like to keep the arc shape in this collection of shapes and take advantage of all the other commonalities an arc has with a shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user2079303's point is a good one, and I think you might be confused about the "full set of operations" language -- that just means that the `Shape` class should know how to do everything you want to do with `Shape`s, not that it should know how to do everything you want to do with circles and triangles and so on. It's okay to have a `changeLineCount()` method only in the `Circle` class, if you are okay with only being able to change the line count of `Circle` objects (things you know are definitely circles) and not `Shape` objects (things that may or may not be circles).

I can't imagine a situation where you'd want to change the line count of things that you didn't know for a fact were circles. It's no crime to use a switch statement to find out if something is a circle, if changing line count makes no sense for rectangles (and I don't know how it would).

Comment: Agreed that lineCount makes no sense for a rectangle. What's causing me the most confusion is that once the circle class objects are put in the the list of shapes, I don't know a good way to get them back to being circles so I can access the member function. Is casting the right way to go? From what I read, in a strongly typed language like C# if I'm casting then I'm doing something wrong in my design.

Comment: @BobC don't treat all these good style rules as being absolute, why do you think there is casting if it's wrong to use it? Switching by type is "bad" because when new type is added you'll have to go everywhere and fix all those switches. Now what if you have limited and rarely extended set of types (like shapes in graphic editor)? Another question is why your shapes (presumably created by user via UI) know how to render themselves? This is what makes you want to expose rendering algorithm specifics in shape interface.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think what does `lineCount` mean for a rectangle.
If you figure out that the concept applies well to all shapes then it's a good candidate to put into `shape` class.
If on the other hand it makes no sense for rectangle then it probably belongs only in circle class.

Now if you have an array of `shape` you  are supposed to ignore the actual implementation. If only circle has `lineCount` that's fine, however when you work with the shape array you're not going to use anything that has to do with `lineCount` because it doesn't apply to all shapes (What will it mean to set the `lineCount` for a rectangle?)

Comment: Ok so I put lineCount as a member function for the circle class only. Now, when I refer to a circle object via the list of shapes, I can no longer see the LineCount member function. When I do want to use this member function on a circle shape, I have to cast the shape reference to a circle class. Is this good form?